# How to convert x/y coordinates from a 2D pixel map into LatLng Values of Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

yesterday I discovered the Google Maps API v3. We were searching for a good way to display a 2D map on a website. Before we never used it for anything so I would say I am totaly new to this :P

The 2D map I am talking about shows a fictive place and is 7150 x 11000 pixels. We converted it into 256 x 256 tiles and uploaded it to our test website.

We have a bunch of coordinates on this map and we searched and searched but we do not find a straight forward written description how to convert this values to LatLng values to use them for markers ...

Can anybody tell us how this works?

Comment: I found this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/yV6xv/79/) example for projection but I am not able to use it for my map. Anybody knows what to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We were able to use the example I posted in my comment to create a projection that is mostly able to translate our x/y image coordinates to Google Map API v3.

The example shows how to translate to a Image that measures 50x50 pixel and we just had to translate this.

Because our map has no square shape we hat to add an offset to the y values and correct the x values by a correction factor.

It seems that Google Map API can only handle LatLng values up to some kind of maximum so we hat to choose a smaller size for our projection and wrote a function to translate from original size to this new fictive size which produced LatLng values the API can handle.